# klee .bca files missing

Tags: llvm, klee

I followed http://klee.llvm.org/GetStarted.html when installing Klee over my LLVM 2.9 (as required), meaning :

1. Install dependencies DONE

   `export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/` DONE

   `export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/` DONE
2. Build LLVM 2.9 DONE

   Install llvm-gcc DONE

   Add llvm-gcc to my PATH  DONE

   export PATH=`$PATH:/home/alex/llvm2.9/llvm/llvm-gcc-4.2-2.9-i686-linux/llvm-gcc-4.2-2.9-i686-linux/bin/`

   Download and build LLVM 2.9  DONE
3. Build STP  DONE
   with `--with-cryptominisat2` at configuration AND `make OPTIMIZE=-O2 CFLAGS_M32= install` at make
   `ulimit -s unlimited` DONE
4. Build uclibc with llvm-gcc DONE
5. svn klee DONE
6. Configure KLEE DONE

   ./configure `--with-llvm=/home/alex/llvm2.9/llvm/ --with-stp=/home/alex/llvm2.9/llvm/stp/ --with-uclibc=/home/alex/llvm2.9/llvm/klee-uclibc-0.02-i386/ --with-llvm-build-mode=Release+Asserts --enable-posix-runtime`
7. Build KLEE DONE

   with `ENABLE_OPTIMIZED=1`

   No errors, but I have the warning "`/home/alex/llvm2.9/llvm/klee/Makefile.rules:1175: Bytecode libraries require LLVM capable compiler but none is available ****`"

However, when I am trying the tutorials, I have the segfault error :
klee: error: Cannot find linker input '`/home/alex/llvm2.9/llvm/klee/Release+Asserts/lib/libkleeRuntimeIntrinsic.bca`'

They were not build at all during Klee compilation. Can you tell me what can I do? Maybe my problem is related to this thread : http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.compilers.llvm.klee/923 .

Thank you for any help !

Comment: AFAIK, you need build `llvm` with `llvm-gcc` again after `llvm-gcc` is built. I did not know whether there's an alternate.

Comment: Now I realize that llvm-gcc is not a necessity, but you at least need a llvm
compatable compiler, such as llvm-gcc/clang.